# Grouping by date and collapsing rows into a single one

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm looking for a way to tramfor the df into the dfres.

Dfres is

```
obj <- date      #where type == I5,
min <- min(date) #where type == I6, 
max <- max(date) #where type == I6,
```

all of this grouped by year.

```
year <- c('2014','2015','2016','2017','2014','2015','2016','2017','2016','2014','2015')
type <- c('I6','I6','I6','I6','I6','I6','I6','I6','I5','I5','I5')
date <- c('2014-06-03','2015-08-01','2016-06-01','2017-05-15',
'2014-04-11','2015-03-14','2016-03-17','2017-03-08','2016-11-05',
'2014-09-04','2015-05-01')
df <- data.frame(year,type,date)

year  <- c('2014','2015','2016','2017')
obj   <- c('2014-09-04','2015-05-01','2016-11-05',NA)
min   <- c('2014-04-11','2015-03-14','2016-03-17','2017-03-08')
max   <- c('2014-06-03', '2015-08-01','2016-06-01','2017-05-15')
dfres <- data.frame(year,obj,min,max)
```

If anyone can help me, not to prepare the data in order to solve this one way around but an "easy" way  throwing a sentence, I would be graceful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea using `dplyr` would be,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 filter(type == 'I6') %>% 
 group_by(year) %>% 
 summarise(min_d = min(date), max_d = max(date)) %>% 
 full_join(df[df$type == 'I5',], ., by = 'year') %>% 
 select(-type) %>% 
 arrange(year)

#  year       date      min_d      max_d
#1 2014 2014-09-04 2014-04-11 2014-06-03
#2 2015 2015-05-01 2015-03-14 2015-08-01
#3 2016 2016-11-05 2016-03-17 2016-06-01
#4 2017       <NA> 2017-03-08 2017-05-15
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` approach would be:

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)
 i5 <- df[type == 'I5', .(obj = date), by = year]
 i6 <- df[type == 'I6', .(min = min(as.Date(date)), max = max(as.Date(date))), by = year]
 dfres <- merge(i5, i6, by = 'year', all = TRUE)
```